# How to validate a file extension only if there is a file extension? Re: carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-3.2, carrierwave, image-uploading

I am using [CarrierWave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave), and I would like to validate file names and only allow file uploads if the extension is `.gif`, `.png`, `.jpg`, `.jpeg`, *or if there is no file extension*.

Sometimes users upload files with no extensions. For example:

http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTCD2TLvYI8a4ChgBaYK_JaRfedvXLr3HXQfj0arXXAii3o2yjf

I am aware of the possibility of uncommenting the following lines in `uploaders/image_uploader.rb`, but I don't know of a way of additionally saying "*allow any of these extensions only if there is a file extension*".

```
# Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
# For images you might use something like this:
#def extension_white_list
#  %w(gif jpg jpeg png)
#end
```

As well, in my model I have a validation as follows, but for some reason `bad-extension.bad` passes.

```
validates :image, allow_blank: true, format: {
    with: %r{\.(gif|jpe?g|png)\z}i,
    message: 'must be a GIF, JPG, or PNG'
}, if: :filename_has_extension?

def filename_has_extension?
  image =~ /\./
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Well Why not use Mimetype comparison of the file in validation process there is ruby gem call mimetype that can help you in your quest

something like this

```
AVAILABLE_MIMETYPE = %w(image/gif)

validate :mime_type_of ,:if => :if_changed?


private
def mime_type_of
  AVAILABLE::MIMETYPE.include?(MIME::Types.type_for[image_path][0]) 
end

def if_changed?
  new_record? or image_changed?
end
```

Even CarrierWave Include MimeType Gem Internally check if that can help too

Hope this Help

Answer (score 0):

`image` is not a `String`, rather it's of the class `ImageUploader` (`class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base`).

Therefore this line is at fault:

```
image =~ /\./
```

Correct it by converting it to a `String`:

```
image.to_s =~ /\./
```

That said, a better expression would be:

```
!(image.to_s =~ /\.[a-z]{1,4}\z/).nil?
```

It makes sure that the extension consists of one to four `a-z` characters. Also, [=~](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-3D-7E) returns `nil` if nothing is found, and this line takes that into account.

If an extension is *not* found, `=~` returns `nil`; so `.nil?` will return `true`; and `!` will invert it to `false`; thus indicating that there is *no* extension.

If on the other hand there *is* an extension, `=~` returns the position the match starts; which is `0` or greater, which is *not* `nil`; so `.nil?` will return `false`; and when inverted by `!`, `true` is returned; thus indicating that there *is* an extension.

Answer (score 0):

in my case I just change in my avatar_uploader.rb:

```
  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png) if model.avatar.file.extension.present?
  end
```

:)